# Function timings in the Matrix package

Tags: r, optimization, matrix

In order to test the Matrix package in R, I ran the following piece of code:

```
library(Matrix)

p <- 50; n <- 500
a0 <- sample(1:(n*p), n*p*0.1)
d1 <- (a0-1) %% n
d2 <- floor((a0-d1)/n)
d0 <- cbind(d1+1, d2+1)
x0 <- Matrix(0, n, p, forceCheck=TRUE)
x0[d0] <- rnorm(n*p*0.1, 10, 1)
x1 <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), n, p)

fx01 <- function(ll, x0) tcrossprod(x0, rnorm(ncol(x0)))
fx02 <- function(ll, x1) crossprod(t(x1), rnorm(ncol(x1)))

system.time(lapply(1:1000, fx01, x0=x0))
system.time(lapply(1:1000, fx02, x1=x1))
```

Is it normal that the first function takes 4-5 times more time to run than the second when the second does not use a sparse matrix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in definition of `fx01`, the matrices are not compatible the way you defined. If we define

```
fx01 <- function(ll, x0) tcrossprod(rnorm(ncol(x0)),x0)
```

Then on my Macbook Pro with 2.53 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor with 4GB RAM and R 2.11.1, I get

```
> system.time(lapply(1:1000, fx02, x1=x1))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.459   0.092   0.546 
> system.time(lapply(1:1000, fx02, x1=x0))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.632   0.005   0.633 
> system.time(lapply(1:1000, fx01, x0=x1))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.078   0.001   0.079 
> system.time(lapply(1:1000, fx01, x0=x0))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.810   0.014   3.805
```

Now this might give a hint (I cropped the output to make it clearer):

```
> showMethods("crossprod")
x="dgCMatrix", y="numeric"
    (inherited from: x="CsparseMatrix", y="numeric")

> showMethods("tcrossprod")
x="numeric", y="dgCMatrix"
    (inherited from: x="numeric", y="Matrix")
```

So I suspect that in `tcrossprod` there is a conversion of `dgCMatrix` (class of `x0`) to `Matrix`, meaning we convert sparse matrix to usual matrix. There is no such conversion in case of `crossproduct`. This might explain the difference, since sometimes unnecessary conversions are costly.

Further inspection confirms this, some sparse matrix code is used:

```
> getMethod("crossprod",signature=c(x="CsparseMatrix", y="numeric"))
Method Definition:

function (x, y = NULL) 
.Call(Csparse_dense_crossprod, x, y)
<environment: namespace:Matrix>

Signatures:
        x               y        
target  "CsparseMatrix" "numeric"
defined "CsparseMatrix" "numeric"
```

No sparse matrix code is used:

```
> getMethod("tcrossprod",signature=c(x="numeric", y="Matrix"))
Method Definition:

function (x, y = NULL) 
{
    dim(x) <- c(1L, length(x))
    callGeneric(x, y)
}
<environment: namespace:Matrix>

Signatures:
        x         y       
target  "numeric" "Matrix"
defined "numeric" "Matrix"
```

*Side note:* This is a first time I managed to get code from S4 methods (thanks for the question which forced me to figure it out), so I still may be wrong.

Comment: thanks: it really didn't occur to me that a transpose could make such a large difference.

Comment: @user603, you might want to file a bug for Matrix package developers. It seems that this is a simple matter of forgetting to add appropriate method definitions.

Comment: @mpiktas (+1) Nicely done. (oh, and good to know that you're on a Mac :-)

Comment: @chl, only because of hardware :) Mac OS X's woeful swap treatment is killing me. Better than Windows, but way worse than Linux.

Comment: @chl, if your swap partition is larger than 5GB sure :) If you know that you will need more swap than your current swap partition size, you can mount additional space as swap. This needs manual intervention of some kind, but on other hand it is doable via R.

Comment: @mpiktas Oups, I deleted my previous comment while editing... My point was about loading or processing large amount of (genetic) data in R which I found convenient under the Mac thx to its "unlimited" swapping facilities (I must admit I don't use Linux for some years now, and all that is certainly of marginal interest to the OP). Thx for sharing your thoughts anyway.